# Trying to post comments to "posts" fetched from the database but it is only posting comment to only one post

Tags: php, mysql, comments, posts

I have a table for the posts in my database and the other table for comments, what I am trying to do is I am fetching all my posts from the database and with every post, I have given a form to submit comments. when i am trying to post comments using this form with ajax it works for only one post and not for others.(here I would like to mention that since this form is being populated automatically with each post, its text area is having the same ID, probably that could be causing error) but I can't figure out, how to fix this? any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

(Note: I am not an expert but a learner only.)

here is my code :

```
    <?php
echo '<div class="'.$row['post_id'].'">';            

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing") or die("<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Unable to select database</span></p>");

$post_id = $row['post_id'];

$resultt = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' AND post_id = '$post_id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC ");
while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($resultt, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
if ($rowss>0){
echo '
 <div>
  <div>'.$rowss["comment"].'</div>
  <div style="font-size: 12px; font-family: serif;">By <b>'.$rowss["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on '.$rowss["date"].'</div>
  <div align="right" style="margin-bottom: 19px;"><a href="#" class="reply" id="'.$rowss["comment_id"].'">Reply</a></div>
 </div>
 ';
} else { echo ''; } }

echo '</div>
<form method="POST" class="comment_form">
<div class="form-group"><textarea name="comment_content" class="form-control comment_content" post_id ="'.$row['post_id'].'" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="2"></textarea></div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Publish" onClick="adcomnt()" />
    </div>
   </form>

 <script>

                    function adcomnt() {
                    var post_id = $(".comment_content").attr("post_id");
                    var comment_name = '.$_SESSION['username'].';   
                    var comment_content = $(".comment_content").val();
                    var comment_id = 0;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "add_comment.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "post_id=" +post_id+ "&comment_content=" + comment_content+ "&comment_id=" + comment_id+ "&comment_name=" + comment_name, 
                        success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == "error"){
                alert("Oops, Comment not inserted!");
                } 
                else if(data.status == "success"){
                alert("Thank you! comment inserted!");


                }},
                    });


}

</script>

            </div>';
            ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion, as I said, I am learning things, will surely look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed, by making a few changes as it was a form inside loop supplied each element a unique ID :

here is the updated code :

```
    <form method="POST" class="comment_form" id="f'.$post_id.'">
        <div class="form-group"><textarea name="comment_content" class="form-control comment_content" id="content_'.$post_id.'" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="2"></textarea></div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" id="submit_comment'.$post_id.'" post_id="'.$post_id.'" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Publish" />
            </div></form>

<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#submit_comment'.$post_id.'" ).click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault()
```

Now it is working as it was supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure, but i think the problem is with the javascript variables "post_id" and "comment_content" which looks not linked to the textarea.

so you can try something like this :

```
    <?php
    echo '<div class="'.$row['post_id'].'">';            

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing") or die("<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Unable to select database</span></p>");

    $post_id = $row['post_id'];

    $resultt = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_comment WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' AND post_id = '$post_id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC ");
    while($rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($resultt, MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
    if ($rowss>0){
    echo '
     <div>
      <div>'.$rowss["comment"].'</div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px; font-family: serif;">By <b>'.$rowss["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on '.$rowss["date"].'</div>
      <div align="right" style="margin-bottom: 19px;"><a href="#" class="reply" id="'.$rowss["comment_id"].'">Reply</a></div>
     </div>
     ';
    } else { echo ''; } }

    echo '</div>

    <div class="form-group"><textarea name="comment_content" class="form-control comment_content" id="content_'.$row['post_id'].'" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="2"></textarea></div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" id="submit_comment" post_id="'.$row['post_id'].'" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Publish" onClick="adcomnt()" />
        </div>


     <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#submit_comment" ).click(function(e) { 

    e.preventDefault(); 

    var post_id = $(this).attr("post_id");
    var comment_name = '.$_SESSION['username'].';   
    var comment_content = $("#content_"+post_id).val();
    var comment_id = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_comment.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "post_id=" +post_id+ "&comment_content=" + comment_content+ "&comment_id=" + comment_id+ "&comment_name=" + comment_name, 
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == "error"){
            alert("Oops, Comment not inserted!");
            } 
            else if(data.status == "success"){
            alert("Thank you! comment inserted!");


            }},
        });

    });

});
    </script>

                </div>';
                ?>
```

Comment: @ Melvita Thank you for the suggestion, I tried this way as well but when I tried like this, even for any post when a comment is posted, the post_id and Comments both are being inserted into the database as undefined.

Comment: Also, again I would like to bring this into your notice that the code I have posted is working but only with the latest post,  it inserts comment for the latest post perfectly but not for other posts.

Comment: mmm hard to say why without testing, try to comment <form></form> tag because you make an AJAX request., try to add console.log(post_id); in function adcomnt(). i m sure you are really cloth to debug your problem

Comment: No luck, did that as well, still, it inserts undefined records.

Comment: if you need to let the form tag, add preventDefault() in adcomnt()

Comment: try to add this in the javascript and see if alert contain good value : $( "submit" ).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
  alert( $(this).attr("post_id") );
});

Comment: I edit my post, i remove form tag and i use jquery click function to post the comment

Comment: it is even not posting anything.

Comment: add some console.log() to verify values of your variables, and see if there is no errors in JS, if your code is a part of a loop, id="submit_comment" will be duplicate , so the JS ll not work

Comment: Okay, as you can see in the code I am using while loop to fetch the posts from the table and there this text area id "submit_comment" is declared...I had mentioned this in my post that it could be the reason, but later on when we added id="content_'.$row['post_id'].'" still it didn't work.
How can i fix it?

Comment: as i told you difficult to debug without see all source, add console.log() to all vars inside the click function, if everything is fine you can var_dump() variables in add_comment.php